# Migrate Graphs in Janusgraph Between Instances

Tags: janusgraph, google-cloud-bigtable

My team is looking at migrating `Janusgraph` data between instances (we are using `Janusgraph` on top of `Google Cloud BigTable`), using 2 separate approaches:

1. Export the graph as a `graphml` file, and import it into the other instance
2. Export the underlying `BigTable` table, and import it into the table underlying the other instance

However, for each of the approaches, we are facing issues:

1. Our graph is quite huge and during the export process, we kept facing the `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` issue, even after setting the gremlin server timeout to beyond 20mins
2. We tried exporting the `BigTable` table via `Cloud Dataflow` in 3 separate formats (as advised [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/import-export)), all with a different issue faced:

   - `Avro` format: after exporting the `avro` files, when re-importing them to the new table, we face the following error: `Error message from worker: java.io.IOException: At least 8 errors occurred writing to Bigtable. First 8 errors:  Error mutating row (  ;�!   with mutations [set cell ....] .... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` - since `Janusgraph` stores binary data into `BigTable`, perhaps the dataflow job is unable to export `avro` files properly
   - `SequenceFile` format: when reimporting these files, we face the following error: `Error message from worker: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 310 actions: StatusRuntimeException: 310 times, servers with issues: batch-bigtable.googleapis.com`
   - `Parquet` format: this proves to be the most promising, and the import job mostly completed (except for an error seen during the downscaling of `dataflow` workers `Root cause: The worker lost contact with the service.`). When reimporting to the target table, data is generally intact. However, the indexes appear to be "cranky" after the import (e.g. when querying a particular node using a `has()` filter on an indexed property, the query completes quickly, but does not return any results)

Would appreciate any opinions/inputs on the above issues, thanks!

Comment: In order to troubleshoot any schema errors, have you tried to create a new instance, write a few elements from your production tables and tried to import them?

Comment: Also, if you're able to import successfully into the "test environment" you could write a script to perform fraction your data and import it in many pieces instead of a large one

Comment: @Emmanuel I realized that in the dataflow job, there are mutation errors due to too many mutations for the file processed: `Could not complete RPC. Failure #0, got: Status{code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, description=Too many mutations: 119306 provided; limit 100000, cause=null} on channel 1. Trailers: Metadata(bigtable-channel-id=1)`. Are there any way to increase this 100k mutations limit? i have already tried increasing the number of shards to reduce the file size (in case that's relevant) but still having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here appears to be that `Dataflow` is failing mutation requests with more than 100k mutations per row (due to `BigTable`'s limitation). However, the newer version of [ParquetToBigTable template provided by Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/bigtable/ParquetToBigtable.java) appears to have a new parameter called "splitLargeRows", which helps split up large rows so that the number of mutations stays <= 100k.